# Error 403 from cloudera manager api in python

Tags: python, api, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I want to list the configuration values of CM. So I have this code that is working on differents clusters (5.9.1, 5.10.0 and 5.8.3) :

```
from cm_api.api_client import ApiResource

cm_host = "XX.XX.70.12"
api = ApiResource(cm_host, username="supervision-user", password="XXXXXX" )

cm_config = api.get_cloudera_manager().get_config(view='full')

for item in cm_config:
  print("%s   =>   %s" % (item , cm_config[item]))
```

here are the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    cm_config = api.get_cloudera_manager().get_config(view='full')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cm_api/endpoints/cms.py", line 115, in get_config
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cm_api/endpoints/types.py", line 340, in _get_config

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cm_api/resource.py", line 110, in get
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cm_api/resource.py", line 73, in invoke
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cm_api/http_client.py", line 174, in execute
cm_api.api_client.ApiException:  (error 403)
```

So I don't have any clue where the problem come from. What could it be ?

Thank you,

Ps : I user python cloudera API v 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question: in fact, it come from the user right. I was not querying my different clusters with the same user. So my reading user is able to query :

- the Services
- the Group Roles
- but not the Cloudera Manager Parameters !

it need an admin account to be able to query everything...

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate user password? 403 error means forbidden

Comment: It works because I am able to get the cluster name when I do: for c in api.get_all_clusters():
  print(c.name)

Comment: Do you use kerberos?

Comment: This code works on 4 clusters, and one of them use Kerberos. And the 3 others where it doesn't korws don't use Kerberos. So I guess it depends not on it. And After some tests, it works on one cluster on 5.8.3. So the problem does not come from the version; So I update my question.

Comment: Can you test with curl?

Comment: yes it works, I am able to get the configuration with myserver.server.lan/api/v11/cm/config?view=full